# Worksheet Change event not working after pasting values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code in `Worksheet_Change`

If a column 9 is updated then the column 8 will be automatically populated by multiplying with col 9 and col 11.

But when the user pastes the values in the column, the change event does not work correctly. Only the first cell in the Col 8 gets updated.

How can I overcome from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then GoTo LetsContinue

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(9)) Is Nothing Then
        Dim aCell As Range

        For Each aCell In Target
            aCell.Offset(, -1).Value = aCell.Value * aCell.Offset(, 2)
        Next
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: But when deleting the data it giving an error. when selected the column8 to col 9 to clear the data the col 7 is populating with zeros. Please rectify it.

Comment: Is they any possibility, after inserting the rows the columns will be calculated.. If i inserted 10 rows i need to calculate some columns like column 10, column 12. Plase help in this regard

Comment: Copied the entire row and pasted in the template, after pasting multiple rows the calcuation need to be done on column 10 and column 12.

Comment: Use `aCell.Offset(, 1)` for Col 10 and `aCell.Offset(, 3)` for Col 12 and simply update whatever calculations you are doing :)

Comment: after pasting entire row it is not working. Ex: I need to copy 10 rows and paste those in the template, it needs to be calculate the calculated fiedls for all rows.

Comment: I have 12 columns. I need to calculate the column 9 & 12 after column 10 updated. The above program is working when i updated the single column 10. But when i copy the entire row and pasted in another line, the calculation is not working. Any help please.....