# Copy-paste doesn't trigger worksheet_change

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Here is what I need to do: When I have written something into a cell in the sheet, my `Worksheet_Change` code should check if the cell contains certain characters and then replace those characters. That part of the code is working fine.

However there is a slightly odd behavior. Here's the code so far:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, "ÃŸ", "ß")

        MsgBox "This is the value: " & Target.Value
    End Sub
```

What's happening is that when I have the characters that need to be changed in my clipboard (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). When I double-click onto the cell, paste the characters into the cell using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and then press Enter, the code works just fine, the characters are changed. (Note: Without the double-click, you can't see the cursor.)

However, if I just go to the cell with my arrow keys and paste over whatever else is in the cell, nothing happens.  I suspect the `Worksheet_Change` isn't even triggered, or else it would at least display my `MsgBox`.

(I don't know if it's relevant to this, but i am using Excel 2010 in a Mac)

Comment: If you copy & paste a value from *within* Excel, does the `_Change` event fire?  [This thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/worksheetchange-not-firing-on-paste/a1cd9b4a-1541-4988-83ef-1c9903f7cb33?msgId=9a4dac82-69dc-4655-9106-eb5f8d4e388e) suggests there is a bug in Excel for Mac, if pasting from another application, the `_Change` event does not fire.

Comment: Yup @DavidZemens. You are correct. It is an Excel2011 Bug. I have not been able to test it for Excel2010 on Mac though.

Comment: No the         _Change event doesn't fire then either. So it seems to be a bug?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020472/worksheet-change-event-not-working-after-pasting-values

Answer (score 2):

You can use Worksheet_Calculate on a trigger sheet.

- Create a new sheet which only contains a link to the range you want
  to watch (i.e. =Sheet1!A1:B3)
- Add a macro called Worksheet_Calculate to your trigger sheet
- Now whenever any date in the linked range changes a recalculation of your trigger sheet gets triggered which in turn sets off your macro

This also works when the user enters a formula in the corresponding cell and one of the predecessors changes.

With manual calculation the recalculation of the trigger sheet and the macro only happen when the user presses F9.

Comment: Genius solution

Answer (score 1):

Always use EnableEvents property when working with Worksheet_Change event. For more details  [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37042)

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 On Error GoTo err_rout


    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, "ÃŸ", "ß")

    MsgBox "This is the value: " & Target.Value

err_rout:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but unfortunatley that isn't working either. Still the same behaviour.

Comment: @flamingo I hope you have pasted the code into worksheet code section.

Comment: I assume you mean the window with the dropdown boxes where i select worksheet on the left ,and then the Change function on the right? The Visual Basic Editor? (Sorry, my excel is in German :) Yes, i put the code into the code section below of that window with the two dropdown menus.

Comment: @flamingo i haved added a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks! But yeah, that's where i had it. It is still behaving the same. If i doubleclick into the cell and copy paste the characters in there it calls workingsheet_change and changes the characters as well as displays my msgBox. However if i don't double click on it (so the you can see the mouse cursor) but rather just go to the cell with e.g. my arrow keys and then paste over the previous content (if there was any) nothing happens.

Comment: You can add a breakpoint  >> Goto Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) line in code >> press F9  to verify if the events is triggered.

Comment: I added the breakpoint on various spots, first the Private Sub... line, then removed that and tried the Application.EnableEvents = true (I wasn't sure if it would interfere, I haven't programmed VBA before). But nothing happend. And i mean nothing. The difference when i double click on the cell and then insert my copied characters and press enter is, i the VBA editor is brought to the foreground and it shows where the programm is currently at. Then i let it pass the breakpoint and it goes to the next line etc.

Comment: When i only copy paste it into the cell (no doubleclick, no cursor), the VBA editor isn't brought to the foreground at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Target.Column = 3 Then
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim endRow As Integer
    startRow = Target.Row
    endRow = Target.Row + Target.Count - 1

    For i = startRow To endRow
        ' blah blah blah
```

maybe it helps

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, please be careful when you format code. You left the `<br>` tags in.

Comment: @gunr2171 - oops sorry about that.  I guess editing from phone is not the best idea. :-/